# Why did my magic mouse stop working all of a sudden?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, mouse

My magic mouse stopped working. It randomly disconnected and now bluetooth doesn't find it at all, I tried restarting my computer, bluetooth, mouse, etc, and still nothing, the mouse is definitely charged.

Any ideas? How can I fix this? It's the magic mouse 2 gen.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the BT module via the Control Center (in the menu bar) by Opt + Shift-Click the Bluetooth menu and selecting **Reset the Bluetooth Module**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was due to my wifi being 2.4ghz. I purchased another router and set it to 5ghz, now my magic mouse works perfectly again.